# Firebase Storage :UploadTask: could not locate file for uploading

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have custom gallery for uploading files to firebase storage it works well most of the time but when i tried to upload this particular PDF file from phone storage i start getting exception

```
E/StorageException: /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents/Scan Feb 5, 2020.pdf: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/UploadTask: could not retrieve file size for upload file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Documents/Scan%20Feb%205%2C%202020.pdf
```

I can send same file to whatsapp and other platforms without any issues.Before creating URI for uploading a file i generate logcat for file path to be upload.File path needs to upload

```
/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents/Scan Feb 5, 2020.pdf
```

Can anyone tell me why i am getting this exception. if it's due to `","` after 5 in file name then i won't be able to give user exact same name of file when he receive. Any help please.

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents/Scan Feb 5, 2020.pdf"));

StorageReference mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            final StorageReference storageReference;

            storageReference =  mStorageReference.child("Documents").child(fileUri.getLastPathSegment());
            String finalAttachmentType = attachmentType;
            storageReference.putFile(fileUri)
```

Comment: I hope it'll help you: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-storage-uploading-pdf/

Comment: The error message is saying that there is no file at the path you specified.  You probably got something in the path wrong. You're going to have to do more debugging to figure out of the File object refers to exactly what you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson i put path in my browser it's work fine. So i don't think path has a problem here

Comment: I am going to suggest not naming files stored in storage that way. In Firebase/Firestore, create a document with a firebase generated documentId, and then two child nodes: path: string and a name: string. Store the path to the document inthe path field and the document name in the name field. Even add a date_stored field to store the date it was uploaded. It's much cleaner.